# Sublime Text 3 line completion package

Tags: sublimetext3

There was a wonderful package called [Compline](https://github.com/astropanic/Compline) for Sublime Text *2*, which allowed completing whole lines, similar to variable/word autocompletion.
I doesn't work in ST3*, so I'm looking for alternatives.

From Compline's README:

> Full line completion known from VIM as ctrl+x, ctrl+l shortcut
>
> Simply begin to write a line, press the shortcut (default it ctrl+,) and Sublime will let
>   you chose similar lines to complete.

---

Edit: *by "doesn't work" I mean it can be installed, but the actual line completion never happens. The possible list of completions is visible, but selecting one "does nothing".
The error message in the console is:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/karel/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Compline/Compline.py", line 35, in foo
      self.view.replace(edit, sublime.Region(begin, self.view.sel()[i].end()), matches[index])
    File "/opt/sublime_text/sublime.py", line 657, in replace
      raise ValueError("Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned")
  ValueError: Edit objects may not be used after the TextCommand's run method has returned
```

---

Edit2: [uploaded screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzuZp.jpg)

Comment: have you tested it in ST3? Looking at the source, I don't see anything that wouldn't work with Python 3.

Comment: Yes I have tried this before. Updated my Q with the error output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

OK, I was wrong, it really does bug out for me too. So I did fix it:

https://github.com/astropanic/Compline/pull/4

You can pull the working version from my fork while the author of the package is reviewing the request: https://github.com/vlakarados/Compline

Comment: At any rate, I just installed it, and at least for me the `ctrl+,` key combination didn't work. I changed it to `ctrl+alt+shift+c` and it worked just fine.

Comment: @MattDMo this sure looks like you have something else bound to `ctrl+,`, you sure it's not bound?

Comment: Yeah, it's SublimeREPL. It uses commands like `ctrl+,`,`f` to evaluate the current file in the REPL. It also looks like Emmet has a `ctrl+,` shortcut as well. Thanks, [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/FindKeyConflicts)!

Comment: Nice one, may come in handy in situations like this one

Comment: Unfortunately simply installing the package is not enough, see my comments above.

Comment: @the_karel I have edited my answer, thank you for not closing your eyes on a non working functionality and being persistent!

Comment: @MattDMo you may be interested in checking this out too